# Где ошибка в запросе MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Выпадающий список берет ФИО и uid докторов из таблицы `doctors`.

В этой таблице ещё есть столбец `username`. Сюда записывается имя того пользователя который зарегистрировал врача.  Пытаюсь вывести в этом списке только тех врачей где поле `username` равно имени пользователя текущей сессии.

Делаю так:

```
<select>
    <?php 
    $reguser = $_SESSION["session_username"] ;  
    require ('includes/connection.php') ; ?> <?php  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE username = $reguser" ) 
    or die(mysqli_error());         
    ?> 
    <optgroup>
     <?php    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row["uid"]; ?>"><?php
          echo (" ".$row["fio"]." ");
          $uidk =   $row["uid"];?></option>
      <?php }; ?
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Но тут не выполняется запрос. Т е Страница загружается до того места где стоит выпадающий список а дальше не идет.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: ошибка в том что запроса нет ))))))))

Comment: не вставляйте код в картинках, пожалуйста. верните в текстовом виде.

Comment: Михаил Ребров, хорошо прошу прощения за неудобства

Comment: @Alex Stassov, а можно увидеть вывод? желательно исходный html код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Какая именно ошибка показывается? (можете включить отображение ошибок `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`)
2. Что находится в файле connections.php?
3. Никогда не храните данные в $_SESSION - время жизни ограничено, есть проблемы с безопасностью

Comment: Как ни странно не показывает ничего

Comment: Посмотрите исходный код, ошибка может быть прямо в тегах option, либо (что скорее всего) запрос ничего не вернул, поэтому теги option  и не печатаются. Попробуйте запустить просто код `echo "SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE username = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($reguser).""` - добавил экранирование, оно обязательно, потом добавьте его в запрос. Вы сможете увидеть сам запрос

Comment: Только ругаеться на mysql_real_escape_string 
    mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\2\htdocs\dental\newpriem.php on line 153
SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE username =

Comment: `Никогда не храните данные в $_SESSION` чрезвычайно категорично.

Comment: ПРошу прощения поправил  теперь вот это и показывает  SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE username = admin

Comment: Я забыл что у Вас mysqli используется, сделайте так mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$reguser)

Comment: Visman, а как реализовать задуманное. Есть ли у Вас какие ни будь мысли по поводу вышеописанного. Был бы благодарен

Comment: DaemonHK , да да уже сделал и описал выше что пишет. Спасибо !

Comment: А должно быть так - `SELECT * FROM ``doctors`` WHERE ``username`` = 'admin'` - запустите пока этот код прямо в phpMyAdmin (только без двойных `  я запарился с этим редактором)

Comment: Запустил,в phpmyadmin работает как надо ...в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Теперь отредактируйте код, который запускаете, как я подсказал Вам.

Comment: DaemonHK , сделал так $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE username = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$reguser)." " )  всё равно не выполняется ((( как и раньше

Comment: Вы забыли расставить кавычки!

Comment: Я что то сегодня туплю ( не могли бы вы подсказать какие кавычки...тысяча извинений (

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое Вы очень помогли мне

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `doctors` WHERE `username` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$reguser)."'" )

Comment: Да да позже догнал что забыл вставить именно одинарные кавычки перед двойными где mysqli_real_escape. С вашим ответом сразу же решил несколько проблем которых встречал на своём скрипте ) Дай Бог вам здоровья !

Answer (score 0):

Не закрыт тег, надо добавить >

```
 <?php }; ?
```

Comment: Цикл закрывается немного ниже посмотрите весь код

Comment: Вам лучше не заниматься программированием.

Comment: @AlexZ, не стоит такого никому говорить. Все с чего то начинали

Comment: @AlexStassov, не слушайте его :-) больше практикуйтесь и будьте внимательнее

Comment: Михаил Ребров, да понял что бесполезно )